# how to iterate over a nested json array and update the properties of node based on a condition?

Tags: json, foreach, neo4j, cypher

I want to create new properties for a pre-existing node based on a condition. To be more specific, I want to create a new node property when a node property matches with a property within the nested JSON array.

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///precedence.json")yield value as line
foreach(link in line.link| match (n) where n.id=link.source)
return n
```

returns an error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid use of MATCH inside FOREACH (line 2, column 28 (offset: 93))
"foreach(link in line.link| match (n) where n.id=link.source)"
```

I have a nested json array called link inside demo.json- i want to check if my node property matches with the property in link- if it does then i want to create a new property in that particuar node

Comment: These details are not sufficient. Can you share what you have done? How do data look like in your database? and What are the issues you are facing?

Comment: I've edited the question and added a few more details- can you please check out and let me know if there is any way to check a condition in foreach loop?

Comment: Instead of FOREACH you need to use UNWIND. This question can't be answered because it's on hold. Can you ask another question with these details along with JSON structure for more clarity?

Comment: here's the edited version with json structure-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548262/how-to-iterate-over-a-nested-json-array-and-change-the-node-properties-based-on